# Dercyption Error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

Tags: c#-4.0

hey every one this is my decryption code i want to decrypt this password but problem is that its gives an error

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str = Decrypt("vASqxLq4dmegE0l3K8T7ng==", "");
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private const string IV = "MazenTech.com.pk";
        private const int keysize = 128;
        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
        {
            byte[] plainTextBytes = null;
            int decryptedByteCount = 0;
            try
            {
                byte[] IVBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
                byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
                byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
                RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, IVBytes);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length); // error this line 
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Password is Incorrect....");
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);

        }
```

how to fix it please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by setting `PeddingMode` property.

```
RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

Comment: your solution is works but it is not doing the correct decryption..
Example "i am encyrpted "admin" so encrypted text is "vASqxLq4dmegE0l3K8T7ng=="... if i decyrpt this "vASqxLq4dmegE0l3K8T7ng==" so its return admin after try your solution no error but not right decryption...